# Geographic Transformation

Tags: raster, arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I have an Image with the following metadata:

```
Projection Information :

    Projection Zone  : 0
    Spheroid Name   : Modified Everest
    Georeferenced to : RSO


Map Information :

    Upper Left center X : 598398.000000
    Upper Left center Y : 506921.000000
    Lower Right center X: 622798.000000
    Lower Right center Y: 473521.000000
    Pixel X size : 20.000000
    Pixel Y size : 20.000000
```

The Geographic Coordinate System the image uses is:

```
Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_Kertau_RSO
Angular Unit: Degree (0.0174532925199433)
Prime Meridian: Greenwich (0.0)
Datum: D_Kertau_RSO
 Spheroid: Everest_1830_RSO_1969
  Semimajor Axis: 6377295.664
  Semiminor Axis: 6356094.667915204
  Inverse Flattening: 300.8017
```

I need to project this image in the WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_48N coordinate system. I am using the ArcGIS-Desktop package. To achieve this, I am using the *Project Raster* tool under the Data Management Tools to convert the projection. The problem is that even after the projection takes place, the projected image does not get properly aligned to its place and stays at the same spot (over the original image).

On checking the layer properties of the projected image, it shows the layer is spatially referenced to the WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_48N system, but unfortunately, it is not displayed at its correct position (which can be checked by adding a BaseMap from ArcGIS online resources).

Need suggestions/ alternative solutions to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Does it reproject correctly in ArcMap? If so, right-click the layer and use export option.

If that doesn't work, I would try using the Define Projection tool to reset the coordinate reference system information, then try using the Project Raster tool.

Based on what you showed for the header, I think the tags are incomplete and that's why the projection isn't working correctly.

Comment: No, the image did not re-project correctly in ArcMap. After some trials, I found out that the error was with the incorrectly defined projection system for the image (perhaps due to the incomplete tags, as you mentioned). When I redefined the projection using the Define Projection tool to the Everest_Modified_1969_RSO_Malaya_Meters, the image repositioned itself to the correct location.